# Oracle JDBC security.AccessControlException

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, appletviewer

Here is what i have..

A file "TestDriver.java" in package "Driver" that connects "ojdbc6.jar" driver to java for inserting records to the database.
A file "TestApplet.java" that has 2 text fields and a button "SUBMIT" that sends these 2 text field values to "TestDriver.java" to insert into the table.
I am using windows command prompt for compiling etc.

It complies successfully and...

> appletviewer TestApplet.java

.. opens the applet viewer allowing me to type in the 2 text fields.

On pressing "SUBMIT" i get this error in the cmd prompt

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission"
 "127.0.0.1:1521" "connect,resolve")

Please help me out. Any further information needed i can comment it.
NOTE: Everything works fine without the submitting button. So i guess i got the basics right but am stuck in sending the 2 text field values getting that error.

Comment: i do not get the same error as the one in the question. although following the guide given is not solving the problem either. same error continues after all the steps have been followed

Comment: They have the same root cause and solution (the accepted answer even addresses your problem more specifically than the error in the question): applets have very restricted rights, and unfortunately the security rules for running applets are becoming stricter with each Java release, making it harder to get it to work.